# How to move drop down arrow to the left of a swt eclipse widget ToolItem

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm working on an eclipse plugin.
I'm trying to move the arrow of a drop_down styled ToolItem to the left of the box instead of the right. 
For clerification: in eclipse the Run button has an arrow for menu on the right side. I'd like to do something similar to this, but that the arrow will be on the left side.

```
new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.BEGINNING | SWT.DROP_DOWN);
```

I expect to be able to do this in the initialization, using some flag, but I don't know which.

Comment: The only style flags supported are SWT.PUSH, SWT.CHECK, SWT.RADIO, SWT.SEPARATOR, and SWT.DROP_DOWN, anything else is ignored. I don't think this can be done.

Comment: The arrow is to the right of the button for a reason. Why would you want to change what is common sense?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann depending on your implementation it might be common sense. In this case common sense would have it on the left side. There is a tool bar that is positioned to the right, at the edge of the screen and it looks bad when its on the right side. you are welcome to check it